# TF270012: There is no shelveset available to check in

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, checkin

I have a question about TFS and Gated Check-in Activity .

My client asked me to put in place a system of build validation on each Check-ins .

But at the end of the build and test process , the check in of the shelveSet failed .

By default in the workflow , the gated Check-ins actitvity is out of "Run on Agent" Sequence.

The error is TF270012: There is no shelveset available to check in.

Any idea ?

Thank you very much for your help .

Ismael

Comment: which TFS are you using? Are you using default build template or customized one?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the customized build process. Some of the following may cause this Error:

1. Placed the “Check in Gated Changesets ”event to run on the Build Agent (The check in must take place on the Build Controller)
2. Build Agents throwing out of memory exceptions (Reboot it)
3. Make sure the  order of your customized activities in CustomTemplate is correct.

Moreover, you can obtain more detailed information during the build for the troubleshooting by changing the Logging Verbosity to Diagnostic. Details of obtaining Build Logs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171470.aspx